# Lubuntu: Add New Printer CUPS SERVER ERROR

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, printing, canon

1. I connected printer via usb and selected system tools / preferences / printers from lubuntu menu.
2. After selecting Canon printer from devices, the URI is automatically generated:

gutenprint52usb://Canon/CP910?serial=CD15052400002998&backend=canonselphyneo

3. system searches for drivers, I enter description but when clicking 'apply' receive the following message:

**CUPS server error** There was an error during the cups operation: 'client-error-not-possible'.

Have read over some other similar posted questions but am still not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Probably cups has trouble handling the '+' in the uri-scheme (system-config-printer doesn't accept it in the device-URI text field either).

The easiest workaround in this case is to rename gutenprint52+usb to just gutenprint52:
`sudo mv /usr/lib/cups/backend/gutenprint52+usb /usr/lib/cups/backend/gutenprint52usb`

Answer (score 0):

Installing smb client solved mine

```
   sudo apt-get install smbclient
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the same problem I've had before, my solution was instead of letting the system search the driver by itself, you should manually select the list of printer model shown to you.

You should avoid the 'recommended driver' if it doesn't match with your printer model and choose the closest model series if the list doesn't have the exact model like your printer.

eg. my printer Epson L565, list only show L455 closest and no L565.

In my case, this method works and the printer prints out the intended document.